# ¿Se puede programar en batch un script que edite una entrada del registro de Windows especifica?

Tags: batch, programación-funcional, macos, registro-windows

Estoy programando en batch, simplemente quiero cambiar la direccion mac de una pc de manera automatica (sin que el usuario se de cuenta). Ya tengo casi todo lo necesario, como el siguiente codigo del registro que permite realizar cambio en la direccion mac, sin importar la tarjeta de red, claro seguramente limitado a xa, xe, x2 y x6... con el segundo valor con a, e, 2 o 6. (pero eso me sirve). Aqui el codigo:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0011\Ndi\Params\NetworkAddress]

"ParamDesc"="Network Address"

"default"="000000000000"

"LimitText"="12"

"Optional"="1"

"type"="edit"

"UpperCase"="1"
```

Junto con este codigo se anade el parametro NetworkAddress tipo string con la direccion mac que yo quisiera por medio de reg add. ok muy bien hasta ahi. Mi problema esta en que puede que la clave del adaptador de red inalambrico no este en la carpeta 0011.

investigue para saber como identificar el adaptador inalambrico y encontre un codigo que lo modifique para que a mi me funcionara:

```
getmac /fo csv /v |find "brica" > macpc.txt
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (macpc.txt) do echo %%a
```

Simplemente busca el token 2 (en el que aparece el adaptador de red usado para conexion de red inalambrica, de ahi el buscar "brica" en el codigo) esos datos se guardan en el archivo macpc.txt y ahi los busca. El echo lo puse para que me mostrara y saber si estoy en lo cierto y si lo hace, imprime en pantalla el adaptador inalambrico. Quiero saber si ese echo lo puedo convertir en otro archivo de texto para guardar el nombre del adaptador inalambrico. De tener el nombre del adaptador inalambrico lo unico que me faltaria es un codigo que me permita comparar el campo DriverDesc con mi nombre de adaptador de red (que si coinciden es porque estoy en la clave correcta, ahi es donde se anadiria el nuevo campo NetworkAddress a mi gusto y el numero de clave que va en el codigo del registro. Teniendo la seguridad de que todo esta en el lugar correcto.

OJO se hacerlo manualmente, pero quiero sabe si se puede hacer en segundo plano, con un script batch. porque si no se puede tendré que ir probando tipo...
el codigo de regedit con 0005... reiniciar el adaptador, comprobar si cambio la mac, si no, eliminar las claves de 005 que introduje, luego editar 0006 incluyendo NetworkAddress... reiniciar el adaptador y comprobar el cambio de mac. y asi uno por uno hasta lograr el cambio de mac. lo que quiero es ahorrarme ese proceso tedioso en segundo plano, eso si lo se programar, pero seria tedioso y no seria lo mejor para estar en segundo plano que digamos... será que me pueden ayudar? debería ser posible no? En resumen quiero que la pc haga eso sola, en vez de tenerlo que hacer yo manualmente, en otro equipo.